# Decimal Field unable to update value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a DemicalField and have a def() for change the value of it. However, the value unable to change through the def(). May I know why?

Models.py:

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
district = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
)
deliver = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
shipping_fee = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.street_address

def fee_caculate(self):
    if self.deliver == 'deli':
        if self.district == 'K':
            self.shipping_fee = 20
        elif self.district == 'T':
            self.shipping_fee = 30
        else:
            self.shipping_fee = 50
    return self.shipping_fee
```

Comment: You don't save your object? Nevertheless if the value only depends on other fields, it might make more sense to define a property. That way, it can not reach inconsistency.

Comment: I have created an object after wrote fee_caculate function, but the shipping_fee haven't change after that.

Comment: but the point is that if the `district` and `deliver` fully determine `shipping_fee`, you do not need to *store* the `shipping_fee` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model and you want to change the value of a field, you need to call `self.save()` in order to register the new value for that field on the database. So you should just add:

```
def fee_caculate(self):
    if self.deliver == 'deli':
        if self.district == 'K':
            self.shipping_fee = 20
        elif self.district == 'T':
            self.shipping_fee = 30
        else:
            self.shipping_fee = 50
    self.save()  #Add this method =D
    return self.shipping_fee
```

Then when you access this object on the cli `python manage.py shell`:

```
billing_address = BillingAddress.objects.all()[0] 
#i'm just querying for a general object here, but you can add a filter, 
#such as .filter(user="testuser@email.com")
billing_address.shipping_fee
```

should show the updated value for the `shipping_fee`.
Hope it helps!